# Flutter- bind json data in Table Calendar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I've found a calendar scheduler [example](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/blob/master/example/lib/pages/events_example.dart) with a dummy data list. How could I bind real data that comes from API? I've to load data in `eventLoader: _getEventsForDay`.

```
  List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // Implementation example
    return kEvents[day] ?? [];
  }

final kEvents = LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<Event>>(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(_kEventSource );

final _kEventSource = Map.fromIterable(List.generate(50, (index) => index),
    key: (item) => DateTime.utc(kFirstDay.year, kFirstDay.month, item * 5),
    value: (item) => List.generate(
        item % 4 + 1, (index) => Event('Event $item | ${index + 1}')))
  ..addAll({
    kToday: [
      Event('Today\'s Event 1'),
      Event('Today\'s Event 2'),
    ],
  });
```

Here, from *_kEventSource* dummy data are going to the calendar event. How could I display data containing `Date, Event Name, and Event Description` in this table calendar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've solved this issue are given below. **table_calendar version: ^3.0.3**

```
 LinkedHashMap<DateTime, List<AppEvent>> _groupedEvents;
  DateTime _focusedDay = DateTime.now();
  DateTime _selectedDay = DateTime.now();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // context.read(pnProvider).init();
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
    return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
  }

  _groupEvents(List<AppEvent> events) {
    _groupedEvents = LinkedHashMap(equals: isSameDay, hashCode: getHashCode);
    events.forEach((event) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.utc(
          event.startDate.year, event.startDate.month, event.startDate.day, 12);
      if (_groupedEvents[date] == null) _groupedEvents[date] = [];
      _groupedEvents[date].add(event);
    });
  }

  List<dynamic> _getEventsForDay(DateTime date) {
    return _groupedEvents[date] ?? [];
  }

  final eventList = getEvents();

  static List<AppEvent> getEvents() {
    List<AppEvent> events = [];
    AppEvent appEvent = AppEvent();
    appEvent.id = "12";
    appEvent.userId = "15";
    appEvent.title = "Calendar";
    appEvent.description = "this is the event1";
    appEvent.startDate = DateTime.now();

    events.add(appEvent);

    appEvent = AppEvent();
    appEvent.id = "13";
    appEvent.userId = "16";
    appEvent.title = "Calendar2";
    appEvent.description = "this is the event2";
    appEvent.startDate = DateTime(kNow.year, kNow.month, kNow.day + 1);

    events.add(appEvent);

    appEvent = AppEvent();
    appEvent.id = "13";
    appEvent.userId = "16";
    appEvent.title = "Calendar2";
    appEvent.description = "this is the event2";
    appEvent.startDate = DateTime.now();

    events.add(appEvent);

    return events;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _groupEvents(eventList);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

TableCalendar(
    focusedDay: _focusedDay,
    selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(day, _selectedDay),
    firstDay: kFirstDay,
    lastDay: kLastDay,
    eventLoader: _getEventsForDay,
    onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
      setState(() {
        _selectedDay = selectedDay;
        _focusedDay = focusedDay;
      });
      print(_selectedDay);
      print(_groupedEvents[_selectedDay]);
    },
    weekendDays: [6],
    headerStyle: HeaderStyle(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
      ),
      headerMargin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8.0),
      titleTextStyle: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      formatButtonDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      formatButtonTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      leftChevronIcon: Icon(
        Icons.chevron_left,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      rightChevronIcon: Icon(
        Icons.chevron_right,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
    calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
      // Use `CalendarStyle` to customize the UI
      outsideDaysVisible: false,
    ),
    calendarBuilders: CalendarBuilders(),
  )
```